# How to fix !illegal.dml.object error?

Tags: apex

```
List<PermissionSetTabSetting> objectPremissionsListReset = [SELECT ParentId,Id,Name,Visibility FROM PermissionSetTabSetting WHERE parentid = '0PS2v000002SPLDGA4'];
Database.DeleteResult[] deleteObjectSettings = Database.delete(objectPremissionsListReset, false);
System.debug(deleteObjectSettings + 'Is Deleted');
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify metadata entities, including `PermissionSet`, in regular Apex or via DML. The [Apex Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2017/05/introducing-apex-metadata-api.html) supports only Custom Metadata and Page Layouts, and requires you to enqueue a deployment.

To modify other metadata entities, you must use the Tooling or Metadata APIs. There is an Apex wrapper for the Metadata API, [`apex-mdapi`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).

You should be aware going in of some limitations and considerations around this functionality:

- It requires a callout.
- You will have to be authenticated as a user with high-level permissions and the ability to customize Salesforce, or use a Named Credential to authorize as such.
- The Apex code involved can be quite complex.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but [`PermissionSetTabSetting`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionsettabsetting.htm) is doc'd as deletable, so I didn't answer. Is that doc perhaps in error?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I think the documentation is incorrect. Even as a system administrator, `delete` yields "DML operation Delete not allowed on PermissionSetTabSetting". It's also docced to require View Setup permission, which shouldn't be enough to invoke a configuration change.